# Как правильно говорить?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Как правильно говорить: "не ругай меня" или "не ругайся на меня"?

Comment: @Раюсик, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Ругать и ругаться, эти два в общем-то очень близких глагола имеют разные значения и путать их не рекомендуется. Ругать значит «называть кого-либо бранными словами или плохо отзываться о ком-либо». Глагол этот переходный, то есть предлогов после него не требуется. Мы вполне можем сказать: Ругать нерадивого ученика. А вот глагол ругаться означает «произносить бранные слова» или «высказывать друг другу упреки». Например, Собравшиеся ругались между собой или Пьяный шел нетвердой походкой и ругался. В первом случае люди высказывали друг другу упреки, а во втором человек просто произносил нецензурные слова. Но вот другой пример: Не ругайся не меня. К сожалению, примеры подобною рода далеко не единичны. Можно сказать: Не ругай меня. Можно сказать: Не ругайся со мной. Смысл этих предложений, конечно, разный. Но у них есть одно ценное качество: оба они грамматически абсолютно правильны. Чего никак нельзя сказать о предложении Не ругайся на меня. Не путайте разные глаголы ругать и ругаться. [Словарь ошибок русского языка](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CC0QFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.k2x2.info%2Fjazykoznanie%2Fslovar_oshibok_russkogo_jazyka%2Fp17.php&ei=xe71U4DkC4f3O4XPgOgM&usg=AFQjCNGVDqFipF2062JUp4OGXr-DCaAqEw&bvm=bv.73231344,d.ZWU&cad=rjt)

Comment: Не внушает доверия ваш источник... Как прочитал про "пиво в разлив", так сразу и перестал внушать. Наверно, в словари источник не глядит, сам себя считает словарем...

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает рОзлив?Не ругайся на меня - это просторечие. Это и так ясно.К тому же и словарях есть это сущ.

Comment: Меня не устраивает как раз пиво в разлИв, а пиво в рОзлив вполне устраивает.

Comment: Вопрос
Как правильно: разлив или розлив вина?

С точки зрения современ-го употребления разлив и розлив как отглагольные существительные (от глагола разлить - разливать) представляют собой орфографические дублеты (см. Русский орфографический словарь / Под ред. В. В. Лопатина. М., 1999, с. 940), но слова различаются употреблением. Слово розлив ограничено в употреблении профессиональной сферой, в отличие от общеупотребительного варианта разлив. На этикетах напитков принято писать розлив.
В переносном значении верно разлив: политики такого-то разлива.

Правильно
на этикетах - розлив вина.

Comment: Niemand , в словаре это слово дается с пометой: проф.

Answer (score 0):

Несмотря на все словари, выражение  «ругаться на кого-то»  существует в разговорной речи, например:

На следующее утро Филька как ни в чем не бывало явился вновь. Стал ругаться на Петербург.

Я ― ругаться на Ладу: «Я целый день на нервах, а ты лежишь отдыхаешь!

И потом еще хуже ― почуяв опасность, глухарь стал хрюкать, вроде как бы ругаться на меня (М. М. Пришвин).

Он как-то стыдился теперь кричать и ругаться на рабочих, грубо обращаться с ними.

Чуть только вспомню и заговорю о своем житье-бытье, сейчас и начну ругаться на кого ни попало.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Не ругай меня (нейтр.) и не ругайся на меня (разг.) - в чем же разница?

В переходном глаголе "ругать" действие направлено на объект, а возвратный глагол "ругаться" такой направленности не имеет.
"Ругаться на кого-то" - это похоже на "сердиться на кого-то". С точки зрения грамматики, глаголы обозначают общевозвратное действие, которое  совершается в самом субъекте, обычно это психическое или физическое состояние субъекта.

Получается, что объект с предлогом  НА задает лишь общее направление действия, но при этом обозначается и внутреннее эмоциональное состояние его производителя.

Не ругайся на меня, не сердись!

Comment: София, ругаться на кого-либо, это уже не  разговорный вариант, а просторечный.

Comment: Этот вариант вообще никакой, его (с таким значением) нет в словаре. Там есть просто "ругаться (употреблять бранные слова)" и "ругаться с кем-то". Совсем просторечным "ругаться на кого-то" не назовешь - это выражение и в приличных текстах используется, например у Пришвина.

Comment: Но если только в речи персонажа...

Comment: В том-то и дело, что не только в речи. Попробуйте в приведенных примерах заменить "ругаться" на "ругать" - у Вас не везде получится. Вряд ли можно сказать, что глухарь ругает кого-то, он именно ругается. И "ругать рабочих" как-то не очень звучит. Ругать - это методично отчитывать, а ругаться - проявлять эмоции, давать развернутую картину негативных последствий проступка.

Comment: София, да, ругается... Но только не с предлогом "на". К тому же, может, во времена Пришвина такое употребление было возможным....Вообще надо обратиться на Грамоту, может, им что-то известно.